# Trying with a Notification

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to show a notification form my IntentService.

But nothing shows :-((((

```
public class CreditcheckService extends IntentService {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    public CreditcheckService() {
        super("CreditcheckService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(999, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Does your notification code work from an Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK

I added the following:

```
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));
```

And it works...